# How a calculated column where 'If [IsNewIsIssue] in the [Month] && [IsStillIssue] on the last day of month returns True

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data set that is

- daily with a [ReportDate]
- has a transient field for when the issue is New, only for the singe day that it first shows up [IsNewIssue]
- has a near static field for just returning true if the issue is still there, call it [StillHasIssue]

I need to find all the instances

- during a MONTH who had [IsNewIssue] == True && ([IsLastDayOfMonth] == true && [StillHasIssue] == true)

I can do
([IsLastDayOfMonth] == true && [StillHasIssue] == true) pretty easily

```
StillHasIssue = 
IF(
    DAY(data[ReportDate]) = DAY(EOMONTH(data[ReportDate], 0)) && data[IsChurn] = TRUE(), 
    TRUE(),
    FALSE()
)
```

However I'm stuck on the first part, that in a given MONTH, it IsNewIssue. Where it needs to look at the entire month. This part would need to be a measure for sure.

Comment: What do you mean by "in a given MONTH"? Could you update your question with a sample table in [markdown format](https://tabletomarkdown.com/)